c# Blazor `SignalR', how to send complex data such as class
the problem is that when I send one line, everything works, but when I send a class to the server, an empty object arrives
  public class Message
  {
      public string? User;
      public string? Mesg;
      public override string ToString()
      {
          return $"User = {User}; message = {Mesg} ";
      }
  }
  public class ChatHub : Hub
  {
      public async Task SendMessage(Message _message)
      {
         
          await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(_message.ToString());
          await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", _message);
      }
  }
}

Client :
  private async Task Send()
  {
      if (hubConnection is not null)
      {
      
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", new Message()
              {
                  User = userInput,
                  Mesg = messageInput
              });
      }
  }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<Message>("ReceiveMessage", (_message) =>
      {
          var encodedMsg = $"{_message.User}: {_message.Mesg}";
          messages.Add(encodedMsg);
          InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
      });
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

how can I transfer complex data?
no matter how I look at the documentation, the video, everyone passes the string everywhere

Add a getter and setter to your type.
